# Nhibernate envers modified columns doesn't correctly track removals from collection

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I've got a model that looks like:

```
class Case
{
    public virtual ISet<CaseToCaseTag> CaseTags { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}

class CaseToCaseTag
{
    public virtual Case Left { get; set; }
}
```

When auditing this relationship with envers, I'm running into problems with the modified property tracking when removing values from the set.

If the **only** thing I change in the case-entity when removing a value from the set is the "set-removal" then envers correctly tracks that the `CaseTags` property is modified in the revision. However, if I also change any other property, for instance the `LastModified` property, I don't get the CaseTags_MOD flag correctly set.

I've tracked this down (I think) to the `AuditProcess.AddWorkUnit` method.
When I only remove from the set only one `WorkUnit` gets added (a `CollectionChangeWorkUnit`), but when I also change another property, another `WorkUnit` (a `ModWorkUnit`) also gets added.

What seems to happen then is that the `CollectionChangeWorkUnit` is discarded in favor of the `ModWorkUnit`, which in turn doesn't pick up the changes to the collection.

Is what I'm trying to do not supported, or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Please create a pull request with minimal mapping to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Great, I'm just in the process of forking the repo. Will put up a pull request during the day.

Comment: Your pull request has been merged, fixed https://nhibernate.jira.com/projects/NHE/issues/NHE-146